# Icing the balls for a woman?

Tags: strength

My husband has been icing his balls (testicles) and has seen some gains. He says that he gained 10 lbs. on his bench or more within a week by icing his balls everyday. I am a woman and wonder if there's an equivalency to this for women, or a similar way where icing of the gonads can benefit us.

By "icing" I mean dipping them inside a glass of ice water for 10-20 minutes a day.

How can women get the same benefit of this as men?

Comment: Amazingly enough to me, a quick Google search shows this to be considered a legitimate tactic for raising testosterone. No idea if it actually works, but people claim it does.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a bit of research, it seems that the reasoning for the practice of icing testicles is to boost testosterone. The evidence is [very shaky](http://www.thebroscientist.com/bullshit-cold-showers-youve-told-far/) with most scientific papers actually being about cold water immersion, and the evidence seeming to show that it lowers testosterone production and boosts cortisol, which is counter to gains.

> One thing is clear at the moment of this writing (November 2015).
>   There is no scientific evidence of a testosterone boosting effect caused by cold-water exposure.​
>   Scientific data seem to report a lowering of testosterone levels upon cold-water exposure.

So, what does help with boosting testosterone? Well, outside of taking artificial hormones, [the following seem to help](http://main.poliquingroup.com/ArticlesMultimedia/Articles/Article/1129/Ten_Rules_For_Raising_Testosterone_for_a_Stronger,_Leaner_Body.aspx):

1. **Exercise intensely** - This is probably a no-brainer since the reason why you want to boost testosterone is to increase gains, but sprints and weightlifting have a positive effect on testosterone production.
2. **Proper diet** - Low carbs, high animal protein, high fat, and reduced sugar are all positively correlated with increased testosterone. And, of course, fruits and vegetables.
3. **Reduce stress** - Stress reduces testosterone and cortisol also reduces gains.
4. **Get sufficient amounts of sleep** - Sleep is an important part of how your body builds strength. This also helps with the stress levels.
5. **Reduce your alcohol consumption** - Alcohol can have negative effects on testosterone, and muscle growth in particular.

I know that none of this quite fits with wanting a quick-and-easy solution, but it is what works.